# video tag without id

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm not able to solve the following issue:

**HTML code:**

```
<video poster="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/star.png" controls="">
   <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;">
</video>
```

How to play or pause this video if video tag doesn't have id attribute ?
I tried to use google chrome developer tools and manually added id attribute to video tag, then tried to play video using javascript:

```
var p = document.getElementById('player_id');
p.play();
```

the HTML changed by me with google chrome dev tools was like:

```
    <video id="player_id" poster="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/star.png" controls="">
...
```

but the id attribute was added manually after page load. And when I try to execute javascript in google chrome console the javascript code from above, I got this error:

```
**TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of null**
```

The javascript code is working perfect on video tag which have id when page is loading. I have tried also this code, which is not working id video tag do not have id attribute when page loaded:

```
var players = document.getElementsByTagName('video'); 
  for(var i=0; i<players.length; i++)players[i].play();
```

How to access video tag controls like play , pause, ... if this tag do not have id?

**Sample Page:** *http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/*

the sample page have more videos , and I also want to pause or play only a separate video, and also I'm interested in how to pause all videos on page.

Comment: why should the element not have an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a single video element on the page, then this should work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].play();
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fEz5B/)

**Notice:**

You have to call it after the DOM is ready, to make sure that the video-element actually is in the DOM when you try to select it. The easiest way to do that is to put this piece of code within a script tag, just at the end of your body element. That way you know for sure that the video-element is available in the DOM.

Comment: it is working on jsfiddle.net, but try on this url: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/
Also how to pause or play all videos if on page is more video tags? 
I also used getElementsByTagName in a for loop but not worked for above url

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel This works fine for me on the site you've referenced as well. Notice however that a few of those videos are embedded through iframes, and those video-elements will not be selected when calling `document.getElementsByTagName("video")`. If you run your for-loop example in devtools on that site, and then scroll down, you will see that all videos that are not embedded in iframes will start playing.

Comment: you are right, iframe have 3 videos, but how to access those videos from parent page ?

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel If the iframe loaded content from the same domain, you would be able to access it's content something like `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.getElementsByTagName("video")` but these videos seems to loaded from a sub-domain of HTML5-rocks, and you will not be able to access the content of iframes where the sources if loaded from other domains/subdomains, for security purposes.

Comment: again you are right, but it is possible to access or execute javascript on that iframe if I use postMessage ?

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel I'm not all that familiar with postMessage, so I might be wrong here, but I believe you would have to have set up an event-listener on the page loaded within the iframe, to be able to send messages to it. You would not get direct access to the content of that page, from the parent. More on postMessage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one video tag, you can use `getElementsByTagName('video')` avoiding to use post DOM rendering manipulation.

Other solution,
Rendering the whole  after the dom when you put the id.

Comment: Needs the `[0]` to work in Edge if that is of any use to anyone. (Doesn't work without it).